# How to perform white box testing on void methods?

Tags: java, swing, unit-testing

I am trying to perform white box testing on the method below. It's a method for blinking an array list (lightUpSequence) of JButtons in Swing using a timer.

My question is as follows:

since this is a void method, how would one check the expected output? I plan to create different sizes of array lists as the inputs. For white box testing, is one allowed to add any codes such as print/counter statements inside the method being tested? I feel hesitant to add any modifications to the method and think that the method should be tested as is.

Thank you very much.

```
    private void blinkSequence() {

    final Timer timer = new Timer(BLINKING_TIMER_DELAY, null);
    timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (lightUpSequence.size() == 0) {
                timer.stop();
            }

            // Turn button ON
            if (!isON && lightUpSequence.size() > 0) {
                int elementIndex = lightUpSequence.get(0);
                buttonArrayList.get(elementIndex).setBackground(
                        Color.yellow);
                isON = true;
                // Turn button OFF if it's ON already. Then remove the
                // element.
            } else if (isON && lightUpSequence.size() > 0) {
                int elementIndex = lightUpSequence.get(0);
                buttonArrayList.get(elementIndex).setBackground(null);
                lightUpSequence.remove(0);
                isON = false;
            }
        }
    });

    timer.start();
    timer.setRepeats(true);

}
```

Comment: I recommend testing at the class/contract level for "non-pure" methods. Modifying the original method just to facilitate testing (i.e. "print" or "counter") should *not* be done, but use of interfaces can really help out mocking.. also, separating the UI from the controlling logic *really* helps testability.

Comment: @user2864740, your comment is actually the answer that I'd pick. Can you post it as an answer? It also correlates with my professor's response to the question: 1) test "non-pure" methods at the class level (need to test in the GUI's true environment) and 2) add print/counter statements for debugging purposes only, not for testing. I will try to separate the UI from the controlling logic. Thanks for everyone's advice!

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is nothing stopping you from making it return a boolean, but if you want to keep it the way it is you can use `assert` statements.

have a look at [`assert`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html)

Answer (score 0):

For testing void method I use the following startegy:

Granulize the variables of the method through globalizing them.

So if you have an array, check the size before and after calling it.

If the size is the same, check the state of the objects in the array and compare them as before and after calling the method, like if they are lit or not.

In this way you can effectively comply to the white box testing rules.